# How to create an index in Sphinx from a MySQL column?

Tags: python, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

In Thinking Sphinx, the Ruby plugin, I can create a sphinx index from a db column. How can I do this without Thinking Sphinx, with the indexer function, or in Python?

EDIT: The column in question would be text.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Thinking Sphinx look at generated indexer configuration ([by default is `/config/ENVIRONMENT.sphinx.conf`](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html)), You can write this configuration with Python,

Use [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/conf-reference.html) or [tutorial for Django](http://justcramer.com/2008/02/24/in-depth-django-sphinx-tutorial/).

Here I found some python API provided by Sphinx Technologies: http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/trunk/api/sphinxapi.py